# disable button until input and file fields have got value

Tags: jquery, forms

I have got a form here:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
Text: <input type="type" name="text" id="text" /><br />
File: <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" /><br />
<select name="cars">
<option value="volvo">1</option>
<option value="saab">2</option>
<option value="mercedes">3</option>
<option value="audi">4</option>
</select><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And I want to disable a submit button until all fields(including dropdown) have been filled out or chosen.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(
 function() {
                $('form > input').keyup && $('input:file').change(function() {
                  var empty = false;
                  $('form > input').each(function() {
                   if ($(this).val() == '') {
                   empty = true;
                   }
                   });

                    if (empty) {
                  $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  } else {
                 $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                  }
                   });
                  };
function(){
    $('input:file').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false); 
            } 
        }
        );
});
```

Please help activate button when input got some text, dropdown has got a value and input type got a file selected.

My fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/E42XA/214/

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just validate on submit?

Comment: Can you help me please how to do it? I am a nut in jquery sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("form > *").change(function() {
  var fields = $("form input, form select").not("input[type='submit']");
  var filledFields = fields.filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().length > 0;
  });
  if (filledFields.length == fields.length) {
    $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("input[type='submit']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Amelle,
Thank you. I have dropped your code to the jsfiddle and it still keeps the button disabled ;-(

Can you please have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/E42XA/217/

Comment: @qqruza Hi! I already updated my answer. It seems that the `.prop()` method is not supported in the JSFiddle (I guess) so I just changed it to `.attr()`. Can you try it again?

Comment: I am conscious about select=>option with disabled (non choosable fields). But what I needed was achieved. Thanks a lot Arnelle.

Answer (score 0):

I would validate only when necessary (and warn why disabled):

```
<input id='mySUBMIT' type="button" value="submit"/>
```

Safari selects the first `<option>` without actually clicking one, so I would also add as the first one:  `<option value=""></option>`

**JS:**

```
$('#mySUBMIT').bind('click', function() {
    var blanks = $('form').find('select,input:not(:button)').filter(function () {
         return ($(this).val() == '');
    });
    if (blanks && blanks.length > 0) { alert("All fields MUST be filled out/selected!"); }
    else { $("form").submit(); }
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E42XA/218/)

Comment: Thank you shaun5. Can you please add your code into my jsfiddle. It seems not working correctly.